# Redis rate limit with spring cloud gateway, limit by minute

Tags: spring, redis, spring-cloud-gateway

I need to limit the number of requests per minute.
I have not found any way to do with spring cloud gateway + redis. Below is the current implementation:[image implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7NZS.png)

```
private void builderRouter(CustomRouterLocatorDto customRouter) {
    customRouter.getBuilder().route(r -> r
            .path(customRouter.getPath())
            .filters(f -> {
                if(!customRouter.getRewritePath().equals("/"))
                    f.rewritePath(customRouter.getRewritePath() + "(?<segment>/?.*)", "$\\{segment}");

                f.circuitBreaker(c -> c.setName("cbServicies").setFallbackUri("forward:/offlineservicies/down"));

                if(customRouter.isEnableRateLimiter()) {
                    f.requestRateLimiter()
                            .rateLimiter(RedisRateLimiter.class, rl ->
                                    rl.setBurstCapacity(customRouter.getBurstCapacity())
                                        .setReplenishRate(customRouter.getReplenishRate())
                            ).and();
                }

                return f;
            })
            .metadata(RouteMetadataUtils.RESPONSE_TIMEOUT_ATTR, RESPONSE_TIMEOUT_ATTR_VALUE_MILLIS)
            .metadata(RouteMetadataUtils.CONNECT_TIMEOUT_ATTR, CONNECT_TIMEOUT_ATTR_VALUE_MILLIS)
            .uri(customRouter.getUriType() + customRouter.getServiceName())
    );
}
```

**setBurstCapacity(customRouter.getBurstCapacity())                                        setReplenishRate(customRouter.getReplenishRate())**

Both operate in SECONDS only.
Example:
20 requests in the same second with.

I needed 20 requests within 1 minute.

Answer (score 1):

here you can find how you can configure for different rate limit number per hour/minute..

https://blog.fearcat.in/a?ID=01800-3ce32767-eb18-418c-b9f2-d16f522fb72b

basically you need to set for 20 request per minute

replenishRate: 1
burstCapacity: 60
requestedTokens: 3